# Is it possible to simultaneously view two parts of the same file RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

This is purely and IDE question.  I have been using `emacs` and `ess` for my code development, but am interested in trying out `RStudio`.

One major hesitation is the fact that I have yet to figure out how to get `RStudio` to display two parts of the same file within a column. [image: Example of Emacs Set Up]

Is there a way to do this in R studio?  I've tried adding a second `source` column, but I can't find a way to either

a. Split it

b. Have it display a file that's already being
displayed.

Is this possible?  If so how?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at this time.

One solution is to open a second RStudio instance, open the file there, and just hide all the other panes since I'm not using them in that particular instance. Saving changes in the file in either one should update instantly in the other. *Note: I'm on Linux and am assuming this behavior is consistent across operating systems*

Another solution for Linux users is to create a symlink to the file you want to be able to open in multiple panes. Just name it something easy to filter in any *ignore files you might have. There's the same caveat that you have to save the file to see the changes in the other pane.

Comment: I find that web browsers (chrome at least) don't play well with two Rstudio instances running at the same time.  There are difficulties even logging into a second rstudio running in the same browser, even if the rstudio instances are running on a different machine / port.  The symlink is a good idea....

Answer (score 0):

I think exactly that is not possible, but you can try this way.

You can open twice the file in RStudio, if you have two windows with the same code you could change between them very quickly!